# ErrorAwarePolicy in Cassandra Java Driver

Tags: java, cassandra, policy, failover

As of 3.1.0 version of the Cassandra Java Driver, there is a new ErrorAware load balancing policy (still in BETA):

http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.3/changelog/#3-1-0 
http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.3/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/ErrorAwarePolicy.html

Is anyone using this yet? I can't find any examples or discussion.  How close is it to being production safe (given it's beta)?

We've been testing the failover capabilities of our (small) setup, and it took nearly a minute for the java driver to switch to a new node after the connected node went down. I was curious if this ErrorAware policy could hasten the transition.